# Preferable design for overriding sealed trait method in Scala case classes/objects

Tags: object-oriented-design, scala

Say I have a sealed trait `Person` that requires the definition of a method `work :: Unit -> Unit`. I then have three case objects `Accountant`, `Doctor`, and `Lawyer`. I can think of two ways to implement this. The first is to override `work` in the case objects:

```
sealed trait Person {
  def work(): Unit
}

case object Accountant extends Person {
  override def work(): Unit = println("accountant working")
}
case object Doctor extends Person {
  override def work(): Unit = println("doctor working")
}
case object Lawyer extends Person {
  override def work(): Unit = println("lawyer working")
}
```

The second is to define `work` directly in the trait using pattern matching:

```
sealed trait Person {
  def work(): Unit = this match {
    case Accountant => println("accountant working")
    case Doctor => println("doctor working")
    case Lawyer => println("lawyer working")
  }
}

case object Accountant extends Person
case object Doctor extends Person
case object Lawyer extends Person
```

The second approach seems much cleaner to me, however it apparently violates the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), which states that

> software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification.

For example, if I added a case object `Nurse`, then in the second implementation, I would have to **modify** `Person`; whereas in the first implementation, I would merely have to **extend** `Person`.

I was wondering if there is a recommended style or approach in this situation? What could go wrong in the first implementation but not the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't consider this to be a violation of the open-closed principle: because the trait is `sealed`, the relevant entity isn't just `Person`, but `Person` together with its implementations, and isn't open for extension either way!